# Can I connect any Thunderbolt 1/2 device to a Thunderbolt 3 adapter?

Tags: usb, thunderbolt

I have a few Thunderbolt 1/2 devices (eSata connectors, DVI/HDMI connectors, etc.) I still have an older device that uses these connectors. Now I'm using a new MacBook Pro with Thunderbolt 3. I noticed that there is a Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 adapter at the Apple store.

Will it work with any devices?

I don't want to spend money on a adapter that may not fit my needs, and I don't want to buy all the adapters again for the new format USB-C / Thunderbolt 3. ☺️

Comment: I know this was from a year ago, but did you find a solution? I have an external hard drive with Thunderbolt 2, but from everything I've read, it seems Apple's connected (as referenced in the answer) doesn't supply power to the external device. How did you solve the problem?

Comment: @YCode In my case it did work properly, but my hdd have an external power supply (it's an esata thunderbolt 2 adapter). I'm not sure if it will work with a power supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter to connect your Thunderbolt 2/1 devices to your new MacBook Pro.

From [Apple's webpage](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter):

> The Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter lets you connect
>   Thunderbolt and Thunderbolt 2 devices — such as external hard drives
>   and Thunderbolt docks — to any of the Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports on
>   your MacBook Pro.